# "The service is unavailable" on existing or new Azure Functions hosted on Linux

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I have an existing Azure function, .NET 6, hosted on Linux, it was working up until today. Now it returns "The service is unavailable".

I tried to create a brand new Azure function - .NET 6 - Linux from the Portal and it returns the same message. On Windows hosting it works fine.

Creating a new function in Portal and failing without any other modifications is a bit worrying. Is there something broken on MS/Azure side?

Comment: Can you share the logs to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Functions Linux Hosting Plan - New Http Trigger Function Published Successfully and working good from our end**:
[image]

There are many reasons that cause 503 service unavailable in Azure Functions:

- Memory leak/issue from the code causing the backend server to return 503.

When a service consumes more memory than is available under the consumption plan, it is evicted. This problem can be resolved by switching to a dedicated hosting plan. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits) for more information.

- Function host might be down/restarting
- Due the deallocation/not running the backend server, there may be Platform issue.

**Please refer to [one of My workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994370) to investigate and fix this issue**.

Comment: I just woke up and checked, it's working now, without any actions from my side. I think there was something going wrong on their side.

Comment: There was indeed a platform issue yesterday, which did affect Linux Consumption Plan - I was affected starting from around 4pm BST yesterday and it was resolved for me around 1:15AM BST this morning. Azure Support said affected customers should have been notified and details in Service Health dashboard for you subscription in the Portal

Answer (score 0):

It started working again. I suspect there was an issue on Azure side.

Comment: Yes, As I told that in my answer, sometimes it was platform issue.