# Azure Function getting 503

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-503

I am trying to run an Azure Function App, that we already have running in a different resource group / service plan / storage account. The original app works fine. But when I try to run this one, I get a 503.

The problem is that all I know is that I'm getting the 503. There is no other information. I turned on tracing in the app, but I still get no messages. I have tried to execute the app from both the Azure Portal Function App Code / Test section, and from Postman, with the same results. It spins for a long time, and then I get the 503.

When I try to execute the function, it is showing me the following in the logs:

```
Request successfully matched the route with name 'IngestRfidScan' and template 'api/v1/rfidScan'
Executing 'Functions.IngestRfidScan' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=a9c37c44-6a27-41e0-bff8-74fbb4275ecc)
Sending invocation id:a9c37c44-6a27-41e0-bff8-74fbb4275ecc
Posting invocation id:a9c37c44-6a27-41e0-bff8-74fbb4275ecc on workerId:7195f57f-b8ff-4613-84e4-9d4bc5dd7c4a
```

I don't see any log messages after this. I tried adding logging to the app, but I am not seeing my messages in the log anywhere. So this leads me to believe that it's not executing the function at all. But I can't seem to find any way to determine why. At first I thought it could be a firewall issue, but I don't think I'd see those messages in the log above.

Any ideas how to diagnose this?

Comment: how long does the function take to complete? Is it going beyond the Azure limit?

Comment: Can you turn on Application Insights? This might help to point to the issue?

Comment: It is definitely timing out. But I don't know why that is, I don't have enough info in the logs.

I checked App Insights, but again, it just tells me the request is timing out, but no explanation.

Comment: In my case there was some error in the Python script, after fixing it locally it worked fine without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check [one of my workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994370) to know the reasons of Azure Functions 503 service unavailable error causes.

> It is definitely timing out. But I don't know why that is, I don't have enough info in the logs. I checked App Insights, but again, it just tells me the request is timing out, but no explanation.

I have given the timeout limits in the above workaround reference, check that and also the resolution.

For getting the logs / more information, you can check the **Diagnose and solve problems** menu in the Azure Portal Function App and also my [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566402/16630138) that shows different ways to see the Function App and Host Logs.