# Deploying an Azure durable function using a docker image in vscode

Tags: docker, azure-functions, containers, azure-durable-functions

I have created a durable function in VSCODE, it works perfectly fine locally, but when I deploy it to azure it is missing some dependencies which cannot be included in the python environment (Playwright). I created a Dockerfile and a docker image on a private docker hub repository on which I want to use to deploy the function app, but I don't know how I can deploy the function app using this image.

I have already using commands such as:

```
az functionapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name <docker-id>/<image>:latest --name <function> --resource-group <rg>
```

Then when I deploy nothing happens, and I simply get `The service is unavailable`. I also tried adding the environment variables `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME`, `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD` and `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD`. However, it is unclear whether the url should be `<docker-id>/<image>:latest`, `docker.io/<image>:latest`, `https://docker.io/<image>:latest` etc. Still the deployment gets stuck on `The service is unavailable`, not a very useful error message.

So I basicly have the function app project ready and the dockerfile/image. How can it be so difficult to simply deploy using the giving image? The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python) is very elaborate but I am missing the details for a private repository. Also it is very different from my usual vscode deployment, making it very tough to follow and execute.

Answer (score 0):

- Created the Python 3.9 Azure Durable Functions in VS Code.
- Created Container Registry in Azure and Pushed the Function Code to ACR using docker push.

```bash
az functionapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name customcontainer4funapp --docker-registry-server-password <login-server-pswd> --docker-registry-server-url https://customcontainer4funapp.azurecr.io --docker-registry-server-user customcontainer4funapp --name krisdockerfunapp --resource-group AzureFunctionsContainers-rg
```

[image]

As following the same [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process,powershell,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python), pushed the function app to docker custom container made as private and to the Azure Function App. It is working as expected.

Refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994370) resolution regarding the error`The service is unavailable` comes post deployment of the Azure Functions Project as there are several reasons which needs to be diagnosed in certain steps.